# Can telegony happen in humans like in Telostylinus angusticollis?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, human-genetics

Is it possible for a human male to transmit features of his phenotype via non-genetic semen-borne factors to his mate's subsequent offspring sired by another male? As it happens in flies ([Crean et al., 2014](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ele.12373/abstract)).

Comment: Note that very few authors really use the term of telegony today. When talking about telegony, are you only referring to inheritance of genetic material or do you also refer to non-genetic material? Because the term is rarely used, I would like to invite you to add the definiton you want to sue in the post (by making sure to state wether or not you want to consider non-genetic elements too). You might want to have a look at [wikipedia>telegony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegony_(pregnancy))

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The question is clear now +1. I doubt we'll have much data on this. The 2014 paper you refer to does not talk about studies in humans so we very likely don't have any data prior to 2014. Note that as experimental manipulation would be unethical in humans, the question is probably hard to study.

Comment: There are also these studies. What do you think of these? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29093734 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23618818